# Check if link contains javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

How can I tell, in JavaScript/jQuery if a link is Javascript?

For example:

```
<a href="javascript:someFunction();">Trigger</a>
```

Trying to make sure a script only logs links, and not javascript, anchors, etc.

Basically I need to capture the href of the link as I .each through them (already done) I just need a reliable way to check that variable to see if it is javascript, ie, function w/e

```
var rand = function() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);
};

$(function(){
    $('#lhcb a').each(function() {
        var rawlink = $(this).attr("href");
        var link = encodeURIComponent( rawlink );
        var token = rand();
        var href = $(this).prop('href');
        var proceed = $.get( "lhc/link.php?link=" + link + "&a=c", function( data ) {
            if ( data == 1 ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        if ( href.match("^javascript:") ) {
            proceed = false;
        }
        if ( rawlink.charAt(0) != '#' ) {
            if ( proceed ) {
                $(this).after( " <span style='font-size:xx-small;'>( Hits: <span id='" + token + "'></span> )</span>" );
                    $.get( "lhc/link.php?link=" + link + "&a=q", function( data ) {
                        $('#' + token).html(data);
                    });
                $(this).attr( "href", "lhc/link.php?link=" + link + "&a=g" );
            }
        }

    });
});
```

This is what I have, but as mentioned below, it wouldn't be able to see if the href is just a function without the JavaScript declaration.

Comment: you can use `indexOf` method provided by javascript to check if `href` contains `javascript:`

Answer (score 0):

A little script can help. I wrote a sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/qXkHX/

```
var normalLinks = [];
$("a").each(function(i) {
    var a = $(this);
    var href = $.trim(a.attr("href"));
    if(href.indexOf("javascript:") !== 0) normalLinks.push(href);
});

$("#result").text(normalLinks.join(","));
```

It iterates through the anchors in the document and pushes every link that does not start with javascript:. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Link can be without "javascrip:t" too. <a href="someFunction();">Trigger</a>. In that case this is useless.

Comment: Edit : if(href.indexOf("javascript:") **!=-1**) normalLinks.push(href);

Comment: No need to edit. javascript should be the first word after trimming. Also href="func()" does not work as far as I know.

Comment: I'm not trying to push any links. I simply need to capture the href and check if it's javascript.